# Magento Collection Issue. Determining Order In Iteration

Tags: magento, iteration

I have a category titled 'top 100 products' and , for now, the collection works fine. But what I want to do is dynamically deteremine what # each product is, in relation to the 100 products being listed. In other words, if product one is listed, I can grab the value so I can add "#1" next to the product title.

When product #74 is listed, it will dynamically say "#74". I can calculate the total number of listings using the getSize function but I don't know how to work with that varible to spit out the proper 'sequence' number of each listed product. The reason I use getSize is so the count can be preserved through paging.

To understand the code, please reference the /catalog/product/list.phtml template. In list or grid mode, you will see the following:

Edit. I can't post this code here. It's maddening. Just need to know how to get a while loop to surround the 'foreach' product contorller loop so I can use while (x) < variable_with_total_products_counted and let x++ reside within the product controller for loop. Every time I try to do this, I get syntax errors. As if it won't let the product controller loop (the for each loop) reside inside my while loop which iterates from 0 --> 99 (top 100 products).

Comment: I don't understand.. Have you a foreach ? why don't you add a counter inside ? Do you have a problem because of the paging functionnality ? Show some code and explain better

Comment: I actually may have found a solution. I simply count the # of records per page, iterate (x) variable as 1 and loop through the foreach loop that comes with list.phtml for the productController array.

While I loop through it with x, I noticed if I have 12 records per page, it will list 1-12. On 'page 2' of paging, it re-sets the first record as #1. So I simply calculate the # of records per page, find the page number, and add it to 'x' and that'll simulate the 1-100 increment of all 100 records. Ty for the time. I can post the code afterward in case anybody wants it. Just debugging it now. TY

Comment: And I found out I was wrong. I promise, though, to post the solution when I find it. I figure this may help somebody else at some point.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$count = $collection->getSize();
$counter = 1;
foreach($collection as $item) {
    // Process item
    echo '<p>' . $item->getName . ' (' . $counter . ')</p>';
    $counter++;
}
```

To ensure that number is persistent, you can assign it to the products and it will stay assigned for the duration of the script / page:

```
$count = $collection->getSize();
$counter = 1;
foreach($collection as $item) {
    $item->setData('tmp_number', $counter);
    $counter++;
}
// Work with products
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I want to apologize for my delay, I was away for the last few days. This would probably work, and it is something I would consider in the future, but I found a quick way to resolve this.

What I did was count the # of total products in the collection, create a variable that counts through 1 and the final total of products and use math to calculate if I am on the last 'page' or not and, if so, adjust for the remaining number of products on that page and append the proper value, + '$x' to create the proper result. In short, I'll try what you did next time :)